# When is Scheduling Class created in Linux Kernel?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, scheduler

From IBM documentation below:

```
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/
```

It is mentioned from the diagrams at the bottom that sched_class instance is embedded inside task_struct of every process.

My question is **when is sched_class created first?**

**Is it initialized when the first process belonging to that class comes into existence for the first time?**

**Doesn't sched_class not exist with 0 processes, just as a stand alone entity?**

Thanks.